# Como fazer a comparação de duas colunas criadas temporariamente?

Tags: sql, firebird

Como faço para comparar as duas colunas: DivisaoCusto e totadetalhe, queria que me retornasse um valor booleano, para ficar mais fácil a visualização. Abaixo exemplo da sql que estou fazendo

```sql
select
    cp.kempresa,
    cp.dt_emissao,
    cp.codigo,
    cp.nf_numero,
    cp.tipolancamento,
    cp.dhc,
    cp.desconto,
    ( select sum(d.valor) from cpmov_detalhe d where d.kcpmov = cp.kcpmov ) DivisaoCusto,
    cp.valor,
   ( select sum(d.valor) from cpmov_detalhe d where d.kcpmov = cp.kcpmov ) + desconto totadetalhe,
   (select sum(c.valor) from cpmov_contabil c where c.kcpmov = cp.kcpmov )  totacontabil
from
    cpmov cp
where
    CAST( cp.dhc AS DATE ) BETWEEN '13.06.2022' and '30.07.2022'
    and cp.nf_numero is not null
    and cp.valor <> (( select sum(d.valor) from   cpmov_detalhe d where d.kcpmov = cp.kcpmov ))
```

Comment: Informe o SGBD em questão. Resposta difícil sem se conhecer o modelo. Tente transformar todavia a sql numa tabela virtual ou CTE.

Comment: Estou utilizando Firebird 2.5 com IbExpert. Queria só comparar esses valores gerados, para ver se são iguais. True ou False

Comment: Você pode colocar essa consulta que você postou dentro de uma CTE, depois é possível comparar os valores como se fossem de colunas de uma tabela

Comment: Do modo que esta essa sql, ela mostra já nas colunas os valores certinhos, só que eu queria pegar essas colunas já criadas e em uma me retornar se são todas iguais ou não (em booleano).

Comment: É possível fazer isso utilizando um [CTE](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-select.html#langrefupd21-select-cte) (Common Table Expressions) ou uma [tabela derivada](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-select.html#langrefupd21-derived-tables)

Comment: Observando mais atentamente as subquerys, se a coluna Desconto for igual a zero os valores serão iguais